# Flexible Animation Tooling

Tags: animation

I'm looking to find tools for building and exporting animations into my game. I'm not using any of the popular engines like Unity or Unreal; for the most part, I've building most of it from scratch in WebGL.

In my case, I'm building a card game, so I don't have complex character animations but I *do* have a couple of things I'd like achieve:

- Movement animations (perhaps as the cards are dealt onto the board)
- Probably rotation
- Some parameterized "highlight" effect to signal things to the player
- Maybe triggering particle effects

That sort of thing. My gut reaction is to use Blender for this and write custom exporters, but I'm wondering if there's any other tooling out there I should consider instead. I'm also curious if there's just a better workflow altogether.

Comment: We generally don't answer "which technology to use" questions on this page. Is there a specific problem you've encountered with the tooling you've tried using so far that we can help you solve?

Comment: I was certainly trying to avoid the sort of "tell me which tool I should use" type of question, and I suspect I did the exact opposite :/ 

I guess what I'm trying to figure out is _should_ I build my own tool for this case or will I regret it later? Is it worth the investment in time to build a custom exporter for my use case, or will it be easier to just build the tool myself?

Answer (score 0):

If it's 2D, Spine http://en.esotericsoftware.com/ if it's 3D, dealer's choice. Probably Blender as you mentioned, or Maya.

The better question to ask, is can you simply use math to produce those effects? Since you're building it from scratch, hooking up the API and a pipeline might just be overkill for the features you're implementing.

A spline is like a swiss-army knife in games. Same goes for interpolation. They can be used to create and pan cameras for cinematics, they can blend colors and interpolate rainbows, they can be used to create a path for your cards to travel without ever needing to animate a single thing in another program.

To be honest, your use cases are so trivial that I highly recommend implementing spline utilities and just using that. If you want a card to fly from the deck to a location, make a spline (or even just linear interpolate) from one point to another. Want the card to spin in a circle? Interpolate the angles from 0 to 2pi.

The highlight effect can be achieved with a shader quite easily. Especially considering you're already using WebGL, [it should be a simple task](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-picking.html) to implement pixel-picking and a shader (or just the shader).

When I make a custom game engine from scratch or if I start working in a new environment, I always make sure to implement interpolation and splines first. So often, that I have them on my github so I don't need to do it repeatedly. Here are two examples, [in C++](https://github.com/nauticaldev/Spline/blob/master/Spline/Spline.hpp) and [in C#](https://github.com/nauticaldev/UnitySpline/blob/master/Assets/Spline.cs).

[Here is a video example of someone doing precisely what I mentioned above **in WebGL** (using the fantastic three.js library) to animate a box along a path.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAfIiop8KVM)

[Here's some examples of entire games in 3D and 2D implemented in nothing but shader code and math, playable in your browser](https://www.shadertoy.com/results?query=game)